# ImportError: No module named nocaptcha_recaptcha, but it is installed

Tags: python, django

I have this site running on my pc using `python manage.py runserver`.  I also have it running on a Ubuntu16.04 Digital Ocean droplet where this is the only site running.

I'm trying to load it on another Ubuntu16.04 Digital Ocean server which has a number of Python2.7 projects running and suddenly I'm getting this ImportError.

I'm getting the following traceback in my apache error.log

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=5404): Target WSGI script '/var/www/crowdfunder/crowdfunder/wsgi.py' cannot be as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=5404): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/crowdfunder/crowdfunder/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/crowdfunder/crowdfunder/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
     module = import_module(entry)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named nocaptcha_recaptcha
```

I've checked my site-packages and `nocaptcha_recaptcha` is there.

I am wondering if I have something wrong in my Apache `.conf` file because my virtual environment is python3.5 but the above traceback is python2.7.

Here is my `.conf` file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.co.uk
        ServerName crowdfunder.example.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.crowdfunder.example.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/crowdfunder
        WSGIDaemonProcess crowdfunder-ssl python-path=/var/www/crowdfunder python-home=/var/www/crowdfunder/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup crowdfunder-ssl
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/crowdfunder/crowdfunder/wsgi.py

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/crowdfunder/static/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/crowdfunder/static/favicon.ico

        Alias /media/ /var/www/crowdfunder/media/
        Alias /static/ /var/www/crowdfunder/static/

        <Directory /var/www/crowdfunder/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/crowdfunder/media>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/crowdfunder/crowdfunder>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If the traceback is 2.7 and you were expecting 3.x then it is broken.  I will usually add some logging of Python versions, paths etc to help debug these sorts of server setup challenges.

Comment: I know it is broken.  I do not know how to fix

Comment: I have never found these problems easy to fix.  Too many moving pieces and too many ways to go wrong.  Suggest logging from the Python Code as way I have found best to verify the environment it is running under.  Wish I could be more help.

Comment: Your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.7, not Python 3. You can’t force mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version to use a Python installation or virtual environment for a different Python version.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton does that mean I can only have Python2.7 on this VPS and I need a different VPS for Python3 projects?

Comment: You can use ``pip install`` method to install mod_wsgi and then run ``mod_wsgi-express start-server`` to have a separate Apache/mod_wsgi instance and set up main Apache to proxy to the second site using different Python version.